# Direct assignment or control with assignment

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I have a game loop

```
class Game extends Runnable {
    private boolean running = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while(running) {
             //...
        }
    }
}
```

And I was thinking if it was better (in game loop) a direct assignment to a variable or a control with an `if` before this. For example:

```
x = true;
```

or

```
if(!x) x = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (!x) x = true;` does **not** guarantee that `x` will be true at the end of the statement. This is because another thread might set `x` to `false` between your testing it and bypassing the assignment.

To be safe, set `x = true`, which will be faster anyway.

Technically, `if (!x) x = true;` is **not** atomic in Java, but `x = true` is.

Answer (score 3):

They do the same thing, but the first is easier to read and doesn't require an if statement.

```
x = true;
//x is now true

if(!x) x = true;
//x is true if x wasn't true, if x was true before it is still true
```